# vuejs v-model отключить автоматическую смену переменной

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Если я в text-field введу значение, то v-model автоматически реактивно обновится. Как изменить v-model только после определенного сабмита?

```
<v-text-field label="Название" :value="item.name" v-model="item.name"></v-text-field>
```

Comment: К примеру в вышеуказанном коде идёт жесткая привязка к item.name, то бишь после изменения input value, item.name изменится во всем документе. А мне нужно изменять item.name например в том же методе, методы я сам напишу, меня интересует именно логика работы подобного механизма

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-v-model-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85

Comment: Зря удалили комментарий, это почти то что нужно) оформите пожалуйста ответ, выберу правильным

Comment: Подскажите ещё, правильно ли я передал $event.target.value в функцию? change_client_value(item.name, $event.target.value)

Comment: `v-text-field` - это кастомный компонент библиотеки. Поэтому там на событие `input` приходят не такие данные, как при браузерном `input`. С `vuetify` я не работаю, поэтому точно подсказать не могу. Но могу сказать, что обычно, в метод перемення `$event` передается первой

Comment: Можете пожалуйста ещё подсказать, во vue можно обратиться как-то так напрямую к объекту без привязки v-model? document.querySelector('input').val

Comment: можно, но нужно изучить структуру итогового html.

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    valid: null, 
    item: { name: '' }, 
    nameInput: '', 
    nameRules: [
      v => !!v || 'Не может быть пустым',
      v => /(foo|bar|baz)$/i.test(v || '') || 'Должно заканчиваться на foo, bar, или baz'
    ]
  }, 
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-form v-model="valid">
          <v-text-field label="Название" v-model.trim="nameInput" 
            :rules="nameRules" autofocus autocomplete="off"
            @input.native="valid && (item.name = nameInput)"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-form>
        <v-sheet elevation="1" class="my-4 pa-4">
          Текущее значение: '{{ item.name }}'
        </v-sheet>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: А когда инпутов несколько, надо слушать событие `submit` (или то же самое `input`) *на форме*.